# How to show numbers from another column over bars in the bar chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-visualization

For the following data:

```
Country | Calls with 3G | Calls with 4G | 3G Phone owners | 4G Phone owners
US      | 10            | 100           | 2               | 10
UK      | 8             | 200           | 5               | 15
```

My purpose is to show bars that count the number of calls per country (I show them in two buckets, two bars in each: US (3g/4g) and UK (3g/4g). But then comes the question: I want to show the owners numbers for each bar as well. How can I do that and what should be the best practice to show it?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 variables that you want to show. You can use x axis, y axis and color to show country, number of calls and number of owners. Play around with it to get the right format.